# I want to install multiple versions Xdebug based in each version in brew

Tags: php, homebrew, xdebug, laravel-valet

I have multiple versions of PHP using `brew`. When I want to switch between for example from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1 I use this command

```
brew unlink php@7.4 && brew link php@8.1
```

When I download Xdebug for PHP 8.1 I use

```
pecl install xdebug
```

It would install Xdebug's latest version until now. So if I write

```
pecl list
```

I get

```
Package Version State
imagick 3.7.0   stable
xdebug  3.2.2   stable
```

When I open `/usr/local/etc/php/8.1/php.ini` I get

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
```

That's fine until now.

Now the **problem** is when I want to install a lower version for my PHP 7.4 (because the newer version of Xdebug is not compatible with PHP 7.4). So according to [this page](https://xdebug.org/docs/compat) I should download at most xdebug-3.1 for PHP 7.

So I will switch to PHP 7 using

```
brew unlink php@8.1 && brew link php@7.4
```

then I download a compatible Xdebug version with PHP 7.4 using this command

```
pecl install xdebug-3.1.6
```

It will be downloaded fine, but I get this issue whenever I use PHP, e.g `php -v`

```
Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace (_instanceof_function_slow)
```

I guess because it didn't know the path for Xdebug.

If I open `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini` I get

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
```

I tried to change the path in php.ini in PHP 7 to `/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so` because there is an Xdebug file in this path, but the problem remains.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading `xdebug.so` compiled for the wrong PHP version. For PHP 7.4 you should see if you have `.../pecl/20190902/xdebug.so` file. Then check your active php.ini to see where the extensions are loaded from, see `extension_dir` php.ini directive.

Details:

The *Failed loading* error tells me two things.

First, the loaded .so file depends on the exported function `_instanceof_function_slow`. This is something that is present in the [PHP-8 branch](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.0/Zend/zend_operators.c#L2286) but not in the PHP 7.4 brnach.

The second is the API Version in the path `/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so`. The `20210902` API version corresponds to PHP 8.1, where as PHP 7.4 uses 20190902. I was not able to find a list on the official site (aside from looking at the source), but here is one [link](https://cknotes.com/chilkat-21-dec-2021-php-versions-to-internal-php-api-versions/) that lists the versions for reference.

| PHP Version | API Version |
| --- | --- |
| 7.4 | 20190902 |
| 8.1 | 20210902 |

My guess is that brew link/unlink keeps the same pecl directory (`/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/pecl` == `/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/pecl`) and/or that the php.ini needs adjusting.

To debug things I'd suggest the following:

- `pecl list` when PHP 7.4 is active
- list and inspect the contents of `/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/pecl` and `/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/pecl` if there are more API version folders (looking for `20190902` and `20210902`)
- inspect active extension folder by `php -i | grep extension_dir`
- check if there are any references to pecl folders `php -i | grep -i pecl`
- see if there are any magic symlinks for extension_dir and pecl
- try to load `zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so"`